# Maple Beer I notice it turn cloudy today

Tags: cloudy

I am about to bottle my first maple beer,and I notice it turn cloudy today.. There was froth starting on it for the past two days. Is this normal?

Comment: How did you make it?   If the froth was during fermentation: sure it's normal - if that's the case wait *at least* until the foam goes away, plus 4 days before bottling, but it's better to use a hydrometer to check fermentation progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you I'd wait a bit.  Ideally you want to be taking gravity readings so you'll know when primary fermentation is done.  Then sometimes secondary fermentation will cause foam/bubbles, you'll want to let that finish.  It's harder to measure, but I go with 1 week after primary and secondary *should* be done.  And note that secondary doesn't mean you have flip fermenters, it's going to happen.  Putting your beer into a secondary fermenter is a good idea to get a clearer beer, but is extra work, more risk of infection, exposure to 02, etc.  I do it for some beers, but I usually let primary and secondary happen in one fermenter.

On a side note it's one of the many reasons I switched to kegging.  Even if I put it into the keg a little early there is zero chance I'm going to make a bottle bomb, which can happen if bottling happens too early.

Comment: Thanks for the answer sniperd. Yes this is second fermentation when these foam bubbles started and then turned cloudy at that point. I had  transferred beer into another fermenter. I will taste it to make sure if is still Tasty before bottling